# Map/set iterator not dereferencable (C++) - Debug Assertion Failed?

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-errors, stl

I have a program, where I have to use maps from the STL. I then, get the maximum element from the map container using the `auto` keyword (alternatively, `map <int><int>::iterator`). However the compiler throws an error `Debug Assertion Failed` and I cannot figure out why this happens?

```
// List.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
char number;
list <char> l;
map <int,int> m;
list <char>::iterator START;
void countRepetition();
int main()
{
    do {
        number = getchar();
        if (number != '0') {
            l.push_back(number);
        }
    } while (number != '0');

    /*for (START = l.begin(); START != l.end(); START++) {
        m.push_back(countRepetition(*START));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        cout << m[i] << endl;
    }
    */
    countRepetition();
    auto x = max_element(m.begin(), m.end(), m.value_comp());
    cout << x->second << endl;
    return 0;
}
void countRepetition() {
    for (auto i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (auto j = l.begin(); j != l.end(); j++) {
            if (*i == *j) {
                counter++;
            }
            m.insert(make_pair(counter,*i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't crash when I try it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ff52de2eb90f28e

Comment: It is not crashing for me either, can you tell where actually you are getting debug assertion failed. screenshot will be helpful

Comment: @Jonathan, Can you in short tell me what actually value_comp does ?

Comment: @Kapil it returns a comparison object that compares the keys of two map elements to determine which is lower.

Comment: @Jonanthan, Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
auto x = max_element(m.begin(), m.end(), m.value_comp());
```

Here `m` is empty, so `x` will be `end` which you try to deference.
May be you forgot to call `countRepetition()`.